# In vue router, If it is possible to use dynamic routering using HTML5 history mode?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Basicall, the problem I'm facing is that:
there is a dynamic router like:

```
www.example.com/:id
```

And whenever accessing it directly through a URL like:

```
www.example.com/10101010
```

I want to display related info by fetching data via server using this id. Any idea on how to could I achieve it? Should it be implemented in Vue part or in the back-end part?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but...

You can show your actual url id using "$router.params".

Of course, you can also access it from your vue component script.

Example:

```
//Actual URL: www.example.com/10101010

<template>
   <div>
      actual id: {{$router.param.id}}
      <!--this shows 10101010-->
   </div>
</template>
```

For more information you should check: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do. First, major changes on client-side code and one minor change on server-side to enable true HTML5 routing experience.

First, the client side changes. Design a route to catch the dynamic route fragments i.e. Path parameters and write a component to handle the route.

```
const MyComponent = Vue.component('MyComponent ', {

  mounted() {
    // If path is www.example.com/1234, then id will be 1234
    const id = $route.params.id;

    // Make API call to get some data.
    makeSomeAPICall(id)
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  }

});


const routes = [
  { path: '/:id', component: MyComponent }
];

const router = new VueRouter({ routes });
```

One last thing you need to handle on back-end side. With SPA application, when user directly hits the page like this `https://www.example.com/10101010`, the backend router will try to find route `/10101010` for which the back-end actually has no knowledge since the route is defined by client-side code.

The simplest way is to add catch all route on back-end which when executed will always send your application's main `index.html` file. Something like [Express.js middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback) would help.